Flush+Reload Execution
I am trying to run the Flush+Reload in my system but could not troubleshoot where I did wrong.
I am using the original source code from the Flush+Reload paper's authors (https://github.com/defuse/flush-reload-attacks/tree/master/flush-reload/original-from-authors).
I have set all the addresses of the probing functions in the gpg.probe file.
When i run ./spy gpg.probe, it starts continuous output of S|r|M as output even though I have not performed any decrypt task using gpg.
I think there should be output only when the decryption is performed. If anyone have done it before, can you please help.
